# Azure ARM policy Template Deny specific Resources

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, policy, azure-policy

I am trying to understand how Management group policies works but deploying some policies.
I have this ARM template, which its purpose it to block specific resources from being created. Which, in my case works, but I would like to deny the creation of storage account only if specific sku.name is selected

this is the azure policy.

```
{
    "properties": {
      "displayName": "Not allowed resource types",
      "policyType": "BuiltIn",
      "mode": "All",
      "description": "This policy enables you to specify the resource types that your organization cannot deploy.",
      "parameters": {
        "listOfResourceTypesNotAllowed": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "The list of resource types that cannot be deployed.",
            "displayName": "Not allowed resource types",
            "strongType": "resourceTypes"
          }
        }
      },
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "field": "type",
          "in": "[parameters('listOfResourceTypesNotAllowed')]"
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "Deny"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/6c112d4e-5bc7-47ae-a041-ea2d9dccd749",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
    "name": "6c112d4e-5bc7-47ae-a041-ea2d9dccd749"
  }
```

and this my parameters:

```
{
    "listOfResourceTypesNotAllowed": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The list of resource types that cannot be deployed.",
            "displayName": "Not allowed resource types",
            "strongType": "resourceTypes"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
            "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
        ]
    }
}
```

and my rules:

```
{
    "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "in": "[parameters('listOfResourceTypesNotAllowed')]"
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand how can this be achieved please?

Thank you so much for anyone who can spend some time to help me to understand this type of deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below policy defination for allowing only allowed sku types of storage accounts to be deployed in your subscription:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Storage accounts should be limited by allowed SKUs",
    "policyType": "BuiltIn",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "Restrict the set of storage account SKUs that your organization can deploy.",
    "metadata": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "category": "Storage"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the audit policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "Audit",
          "Deny",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "Deny"
      },
      "listOfAllowedSKUs": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "The list of SKUs that can be specified for storage accounts.",
          "displayName": "Allowed SKUs",
          "strongType": "StorageSKUs"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sku.name",
              "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedSKUs')]"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/7433c107-6db4-4ad1-b57a-a76dce0154a1",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "7433c107-6db4-4ad1-b57a-a76dce0154a1"
}
```

**Reference:**

[List of built-in policy definitions - Azure Policy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies)

[Storage accounts should be limited by allowed SKUs- policy](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F7433c107-6db4-4ad1-b57a-a76dce0154a1)